# Converting array into columns in hive when array size varies

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This is the schema of my table that I want to use to generate some data:

Houses table:
data, created_at

sample row:

{attr1,
attr2,
[{type:car, quantity:1},{type:bike,quantity:2}],
attr3,
[{id:room1id},{id:room2id},{id:room3id}]}, '2014-11-1'

I have to explode this along rooms so that my result looks like this:

room1id attr1 attr2

room2id attr1 attr2

room3id attr1 attr2

For this I use the following query

```
select r.id,h.data.attr1,h.data.attr2 from houses h lateral view explode(h.data.rooms) table as r
```

This works fine. Now I need the information regarding vehicles appended to my result in the following format:

> id      A1    A2    car_quantity bike_quantity
>
> room1id attr1 attr2 1            2
>
> room2id attr1 attr2 1            2
>
> room3id attr1 attr2 1            2

How do I achieve this? The thing that comes to my mind is to loop over the vehicles and then have a case of the type of the vehicle but I can't find how to do this in hive. A lateral view explode over vehicles is of no use since it returns 6 rows. The number of elements in that vehicle array can vary (can be 0,1,2) but it would always be of type either car or bike.